# Is it possible importing Azure VM backup or snapshot from different account?

Tags: azure

I have a simple question about Microsoft Azure.
When I use a free trial, can I backup VM image(snapshot?)
and import it from different account VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can even transfer the VHD to your machine. Or even to Amazon S3.

Comment: oh, I didn't think it's possible. Thank you for the reply.